# Keras fit using validation_split gets higher results than using validation_data

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am using the following *fit* function:

```
history = model.fit(x=[X1_train, X2_train, X3_train],
                y=y_train,
                batch_size=50,
                epochs=20,
                verbose=2,
                validation_split=0.3,
                #validation_data=([X1_test, X2_test, X3_test], y_test),
                class_weight={0:1, 1:10})
```

and getting average val_acc of 0.7. But when running again, this time with the validation_data option (using data from the same dataset that I kept aside, of size around 30% of train data) I am getting an average val_acc of 0.35. Any reasons for getting such differences?

Comment: Are you sure the proportion of classes in the validation data, i.e. `y_test` is the same as in training data, i.e. `y_train`? And is it the same as the proportion of classes in the last 30% samples in `y_train`?

Comment: You are right. They were indeed different. Can you please post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by the OP, I am posting my comment as an answer and try to elaborate more:

When you set the `validation_split` argument, the validations samples are selected from the last samples in the training data and labels (i.e. `X_train` and `y_train`). Now, in this specific case, if the proportion of class labels in these selected samples is not the same as the proportion of the class labels in the data you provide using `validation_data` argument, then you should not necessarily expect the validation loss to be the same in these two cases. And that's simply because your model may have different accuracy on each of the classes.